# Install for all users an Application from a DMG

Tags: applications, bash, dmg

I trying to install with a Bash script an Application like Slack when I create a new Macbook.

Connected as the admin user I run those command

```
sudo hdiutil attach -nobrowse /Users/admin/Desktop/post-install/Slack.dmg
sudo rsync -a /Users/admin/Desktop/post-install/Slack.app /Applications/
hdiutil detach -quiet /Volumes/Slack.app
```

As you can see I installed those applications in the root /Applications folder.
But when I trying to logged in with another account the app do not exist. 
I can only see the Slack application when I'm connected with the admin account.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: It's most likely a permissions issue.  If I install manually, I don't need admin privileges to install - you're rsync'ing as root (sudo).  Also, why not just copy (`cp`) instead?

Comment: I test on Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: rsync was to avoid re-copying when the app already exist (it's a legacy thing). But yeah i can understand the permission problem but in this case how can i change the permissions after the rsync or cp to allowed everyone to see and use those apps ?

Comment: Are you sure that the paths you use are correct, especially the source path for `rsync`?

Comment: check the resulting permissions:  ls -l /Applications/;  ls -la@hbefO /Applications/; chmod 555 /Applications/*;  # you will need to fix up the chmod command as needed. please report results from the list command for further help;  more details on the ls command: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250286154?answerId=250536204022#250536204022